# WPF Spellcheck shows abbreviations as error, because of trailing dot

Tags: c#, wpf, spell-checking, abbreviation

I am experiencing a problem with WPF built-in SpellCheck for Textbox, when i am using an abbreviation, for example "e.g." for "en" language.

The word gets underlined, but not the trailing dot. In the list of suggestions the same word is provided, but with a dot ("e.g."). Clicking it, results in following: "e.g..". And "e.g" part is underlined again.

I could reproduce it on Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012. I have tried to install 4.7 .Net Framework and target different frameworks (4.5, 4.6, 4.7) in the application, but issue still persists.
On Windows 7 machine this issue is not present.

Here is a demonstration:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwHi9.jpg)

The code itself is basically:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox SpellCheck.IsEnabled="true" Language="en"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Well, don't hesitate to use the backspace key to correct.  You cannot assume that a spell-checker will always get it 100% correct, it works with imperfect data.  No different from the one you used to type this SO question, it somehow did not correct the lowercase `i`.

Comment: @HansPassant the red squiggle will remain regardless of using the backspace key to correct. I could see this being a problem for less forgiving end users, especially if they are typing an abbreviation frequently.